# pdf.js import undefined for web component

Tags: javascript, pdf, web-component, pdf.js, lit-html

I am trying to write a web component using lit-html which will render a user selected PDF file using pdf.js. However pdf.js import gives me the following error:

```
import 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js';

TypeError: "root is undefined"
    webpackUniversalModuleDefinition http://localhost:8003/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:21
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8003/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js:21
```

I can render a pdf file if I use a script tag for pdf.js in an html file.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
import * as pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! You can improve your answer by explaining why the modification you've suggested will help, or why it works.